# PERMISSION_DENIED when calling REST runQuery Datastore API from Android as a project non-owner

Tags: android, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to run [runQuery REST method](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/v1beta2/datasets/runQuery) from an Android App.  The query runs and returns correct results if I log-in using a project owner account.  If I login using a non-project owner account, I'm getting a PERMISSION_DENIED response:

```
{
   "error": {
      "errors": [
         {
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
            "message": "Unauthorized."
         }
      ],
      "code": 403,
      "message": "Unauthorized."
   }
}
```

My goal is to be able to run queries as non-project owner.  Is it possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cloud Datastore API currently requires the caller to be in one of the admin roles on the project.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Ed.  Are there plans to make APIs work for non-admin callers?